# Java - Returning a new array with elements in even positions from a given array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and I am stuck on a problem that requires me to return a new array containing only the even-numbered elements from a given array. The method should consider arrays of odd or even length and zero or one element in the array. The length should be exact so there are no extra zeros at the end of the array.

```
public static int[] everyOther(int[] arr){
    int nArrayL;
    if (arr.length < 2){
        return arr;
    }  
    else{
        if (arr.length % 2 == 0){
            nArrayL = arr.length / 2;
        }
        else{nArrayL = arr.length / 2 + 1;
        }
    }
    int[] nextArray = new int[nArrayL];
    int count = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x +=2){
        nextArray[count] = x;
        count++;
    }
    return nextArray;
}
```

Here is my attempt to the problem and it is compiling but not passing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry I pressed enter before I managed to complete the post. I edited it to put my attempt.

Comment: Fair enough, and thank you for that

Comment: Is the first element of the array (position 0) considered odd or even?

Comment: you should assign the element of the array to nextArray[count] and not the index 'x'. it should be nextArray[count]=arr[x]

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am working with an automatic tester and in theory, I don't see any potential errors in output but there still seems to be a bug in my code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would say even but the code does not pass even if I change it into just if(arr.length == 1){ return arr;}

Comment: @Abi and Willis Blackburn have solved your bug, it seems

Comment: @Abi wow I can't believe I overlooked something that simple! It worked and the code passed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sometimes it takes another set of eyes to see what we can't

Comment: @nemajeff: "Solved" removed from your title. That's not done here. Accepting an answer is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is basically correct. I think the only error is that you're copying the array index into the output array, instead of the element at the array index.

A couple of other suggestions:

- You don't need the "else" because you're returning in the "if" statement. The whole rest of the function is "else."
- Instead of handling the odd and even cases separately, you can just do `(arr.length + 1) / 2`.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and thank you for helping me notice that error

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, the mistake was copying `x` into the array (instead of `arr[x]`). However, you can eliminate `count` (because it is always one half of `x`). You could also invert that identity (e.g. `i` and `i*2` as indices). Simplifying the code then leaves something like,

```
public static int[] everyOther(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    }
    int[] nextArray = new int[(arr.length + 1) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < nextArray.length; i++) {
        nextArray[i] = arr[i * 2];
    }
    return nextArray;
}
```

And if you're using Java 8+, you might use an `IntStream` and then map each index with the same algorithm. Like,

```
public static int[] everyOther(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, (arr.length + 1) / 2).map(i -> arr[i * 2]).toArray();
}
```